# mod_rewrite only for special subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want a rewrite rule only for a special subdirectory
e.g.: Every file/directory that is not existing inside the directory `www.domain.com/apps/myapp/[*]`, should rewrite to `www.domain.com/apps/myapp/index.html`.

It is important, that this rule is only applied for url starting with `/apps/myapp`

How to build this rule up, as I am totally new to mod_rewrite?
Is it possible to achieve this with an .htaccess inside `/apps/myapp`?

**Update**

got it to work with the following, the `.htaccess` file is located inside `/apps/myapp`, as wanted:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /apps/myapp/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html [L]
```

any suggestions for improvements?

Comment: `.htaccess` has directory context and both `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` are allowed in directory context, so I guess the answer is yes. Do you have any problem in particular? In any case, I think `FallbackResource` is more straightforward for the use case you describe.

Comment: got it to work. updated my post. How to use FallbackResource? Could you post an examlpe?